# design view freezes in visual studio 2008 web application

Tags: asp.net

i have visual studio 2008 and ms office 2007..when i try to develop a web application in vs 2008, i didnt able to open the design view of the web page.. i can only able to see the source view..came to know by googling as, there is some compatibility issues between vs 2008 and ms office 2007 in web authoring components.. please help me to overcome this issue...thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone...
i solved this issue by uninstalling ms office 2007 from my system.. there is some compatibility issue between ms office 2007 and vs 2008 web components...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [reinstalling the Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2010/03/29/visual-studio-2008-hangs-in-design-view-with-asp-net-web-page.aspx)